# Laravel-developed website looks different on localhost than on webhost despite the exact same files

Tags: css, laravel, responsive-design

Straight to the point.

I've created a website on Laravel framework, uploaded it to a server and for some reason - this is how it looks on my phone when tested ON the server and ON the local host accessed via (192.168.1.2)

**Web host**

[image: webhost]

**Local host**

[image: localhost]

Both server and localhost have identical files, the only difference is lack of garbage graphical files in the storage.

Comment: Are you linking to external files? This could be an issue with http linking to https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was only editting the CSS file for past 3-4 hours so I thought to myself 'I only have to upload the css file', but I forgot that in the very beginning I've added

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

To the main template file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some CSS files can be loaded in one case and not on the other. Things to consider:

- Are there hardcoded URLs for your CSS files (pointing to e.g. 192.168.1.2)?
- Try opening the developer tools for the browser you're using on your phone. Then in the network tab, look for 404 errors.

I know this sounds like a dummy answer...